# How to use dynamic route parts in Blazor WASM app

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm about to implement a Blazor WASM app with the following requirement: The app should be used by users that can manage several organizations and sub-organizations.

Therefore I want to separate most of the pages with the following url structure: `myapp.test/[organization]/[sub-organization]/[page]`
Is there a way that blazor routing handle such requests like `myapp.test/[page]` but provides me the values for organization and sub-organization? I just saw samples with custom Router implementations that handle areas to match them to a namespace in the page folder, but could not find information about dynamic route parts that are converted to values.

As it should be a client side app, I think I cannot use proxies like nginx to restructure my urls to a form like `myapp.test/[page]?organization=[organization]&&sub=[sub-organization]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create your component with a route like

```
@page "/{Organization}/{SubOrganization}/{Page:int}"
```

With such a route, `Organization` is now a parameter you can use in your component.

```
@code{
    [Parameter]
    public String Organization { get; set; }
}
```

You can constraint the route parameters, like `{Page:int}` and since .NET 5, parameters can be optional by adding a `?` at the end like `{Page:int?}`.

Here is a quick demo.

```
@page "/{Organization}/{SubOrganization}/{Page:int?}"

<dl>
    <dt>Organization</dt>
    <dd>@Organization</dd>

    <dt>Sub Organization</dt>
    <dd>@SubOrganization</dd>

    <dt>Page</dt>
    <dd>@Page</dd>
</dl>

@code{

    [Parameter]
    public String Organization { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public String SubOrganization { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public Int32 Page { get; set; } = 1;

}
```

[image: Paramters in URLs]

The [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#route-parameters) has a solid explanation, and https://blazor-university.com/routing/route-parameters/ has a good tutorial as well.

Comment: That was exactly the approach I was looking for but to blind to find. Thanks a lot.